# Math directives in Django ReStructuredText

Tags: python, django, django-templates, restructuredtext, docutils

I am using Django template restructuredtext filter to display an rst file in my template. 
I have `docutils` installed, and have added `django.contrib.markup` to `settings.py`. Displaying rst text works fine.

Now, I want to add some math to the rst file:

test.rst:

```
.. math::
    16 \div 2

The equation is :math:`16 \div 2`.
```

Update:: I fixed this partially. Initially, the errors were `Unknown directive`. I was trying to add math directives to the template, but then realized that docutils 0.10 supports math directives by default. Hence just upgraded to docutils-0.10.

However, now what I see is:

```
\begin{equation*} 16 \div 2 \end{equation*}
The equation is \(16 \div 2\)
```

The the rst file works fine if I do `rst2html` and check it in the browser. The difference is that the html file loads MathJax javascript while Django template does not add the js file.

So I am guessing that some setting or config is missing...

Would really appreciate a helping hand here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this with 2 things:

1. Initial errors were `Unknown directive`. I was trying to add math directives to the template to load latex, but then realized that docutils 0.10 supports math directives by default. Hence just upgraded to docutils-0.10.
2. After that the error was that I was seeing the latex math code enclosed in `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}` tags. Comparing the output of rst2html and django template filter, I realized that the MathJax javascript needed to do latex is not added by django restructuredtext filter. So, in my template file  section, I manually added:

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>`

Now, it works!

Comment: If you have an https page, use  `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>` instead of the above link.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).